# How to use .destory() on <TinySlider></TinySlider>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spfx

I am having an issue with TinySlider and I think If I can use the rebuild() and the destroy() methods I may be able to fix the issue/bug.

However, how in hell do you use .destroy() on a component like  ?

https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider

(I am coming from jQuery so a bit of a learning curve for me right now)

Thanks!

My code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      profiles: [],
      isLoading: true,
      errors: null
  };
  SPComponentLoader.loadCss('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny- slider/2.9.2/tiny-slider.css');
}

if (this.props.toggleInfoHeaderValue == true ) {
  return(
    <TinySlider settings={...settings}>
      {renderProfilesCarousel}
    </TinySlider>
  )
}
else {
  return (
    <div className={styles.upArrows}>
      <TinySlider settings={...settings}>
        {renderProfiles }
      </TinySlider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance for slider as follows:

```
  import {tns} from './src/tiny-slider.js';

  var slider = tns({
    container: '.my-slider',
    items: 3,
    slideBy: 'page',
    autoplay: true
  });
```

with that instance as a reference you can call destroy function as follows: `slider.destroy()`

If you are passing generated to the child then add `slider.destroy()` under some function called maybe `destroySlider()` and pass that to the child through props. The same function you can call from child whenever you want to destroy slider.